# Why is my nginx reverse proxy not working? (macos)

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew, reverse-proxy

I installed nginx using brew install nginx

[Screenshot of the terminal commands and their results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HXXi.png)

I started nginx using brew services start nginx

I changed the usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf file to add a new location and i changed the user to mobi staff

I added

```
location /p1/ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/product;
}

location /p2/ {
   proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
}
```

Neither of the proxy pass things are working, i added the google.com one to test if it would work but when i go to localhost:8080/p1/ or localhost:8080/p2/ i get a 404 not found. How do I fix this so I can setup a reverse proxy that will go to those links?

[Screen shot of the install and nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ2GD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I moved the

```
location /p1/ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/product;
}

location /p2/ {
   proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
}
```

code to be just below the server

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /p1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/product;
    }
    location /p2/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
    }
```

and then instead of running

```
sudo brew services restart nginx
```

I ran

```
brew services restart nginx
```

and it works i get redirected to the urls now!

Comment: OH AND P.S i also deleted the default nginx conf file at
/usr/local/etc/nginx